# I am using a payment gateway that sends an approved or declined response in plain text

Tags: php, plaintext

I am using a payment gateway that sends an approved or declined response in plain text (comma delimited). How can I capture that response in PHP? I need to be able explode the response into an array and use some of the data.

Comment: Have you looked into `cURL`? http://sg3.php.net/curl

Comment: gateway api should have documentation, and most have example code.